# @@SERVERNAME vs serverproperty('servername')

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select @@SERVERNAME    
select serverproperty('servername')**
```

returns different result, Why?

Comment: Although the @@SERVERNAME function and the SERVERNAME property of SERVERPROPERTY function may return strings with similar formats, the information can be different. The SERVERNAME property automatically reports changes in the network name of the computer. [@@SERVERNAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/us-en/library/ms187944.aspx)

Comment: [Rename a Computer that Hosts a Stand-alone instance of SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms143799.aspx) describes the steps that someone should have followed if they've renamed the machine (or created a new machine from an image)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187944.aspx

> Although the @@SERVERNAME function and the SERVERNAME property of
>   SERVERPROPERTY function may return strings with similar formats, the
>   information can be different. The SERVERNAME property automatically
>   reports changes in the network name of the computer.
>
> In contrast, @@SERVERNAME does not report such changes. @@SERVERNAME
>   reports changes made to the local server name using the sp_addserver
>   or sp_dropserver stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

@@SERVERNAME is the name entry from sys.servers with server_id = 0 and can even be NULL, whilst SERVERPROPERTY( 'ServerName' ) returns the Network name and can never be NULL.

So I usually use ISNULL( @@SERVERNAME, SERVERPROPERTY( 'ServerName' ) ).